# URL rewrite for dynamic websites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my dynamic URLs here is some information about it.

Entire data is coming from single table no other table created.
URL Rewrite is active on Apache server.

**MY CURRENT URL**

http://www.example.com/list.php?city=Mumbai&business_category=Accounting+services

**EXPECTED URL**

http://www.example.com/Mumbai/Accounting-services

**MY CODE**

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    list.php?city=$1&business_category=$2    [NC,L]    # Process product requests
```

Comment: Actually that looks fine. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Nothing is happening to my URL its stays the same as it is.

Comment: Are you expecting the current url to be transformed into the expected url when it is entered into the addressbar?

Comment: when u select city and business category after hitting submit button you get current URLI want that to trun in to expected url.

Comment: Ok. Then it has nothing to do with htaccess. You need to change the `action` attribute of the form. Your htaccess is then already set to handle it.

Comment: Can you help me with that ? I use get method in my form.

Comment: What change should I make in my form code to get that work.  – colburton

Comment: perhaps you should post the html form as part of the question?!

Answer (score 0):

You could give the following a try - I think it does more or less what you were after

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:list\.php)?\?city=([^&\s]+)&business_category=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: I don't think he wanted a redirect.

Comment: Found nothing but here is return URL http://www.example.com/home/wwwexample/Kalyan/Accounting+services

Comment: What I want is if I fond something in my city using business category I am getting that using my current url but I want it to display like others url www.example.com/(selected city)/(selected business category) and in result I get the list of results.